# Ignore TS errors in project with yarn workspaces

Tags: typescript

I have a repo using yarn workspaces. When running `tsc --noEmit` to type check my code from within the workspace folder, errors are being reported for packages that are being stored at the top level `node_modules`

```
../../node_modules/create-emotion-styled/types/index.d.ts:5:24 - error TS7016: ...
../../node_modules/create-react-context/lib/index.d.ts:1:24 - error TS7016: ...
../../node_modules/react-i18next/index.d.ts:1:24 - error TS7016: ...
```

All errors are about not finding react types:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react'.
```

I have `@types/react` installed locally in my workspace, but regardless, from the docs:

> The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and  directories when not specified.

I've also tried `exclude: ["**/node_modules", "**/node_modules/**"]` without success.

So why are these errors being thrown?

Comment: is the problem only with typechecking with `tsc --noEmit`? Is the problem the same for compiling the sources? How do you compile your project?

Comment: I compile with webpack and babel

Comment: Babel can only transpile, but not type-check the typescript source code. It means, that the problem could have been there for some time. Try updating `create-emotion-styled`, `create-react-context` and `react-i18next` to see whether there are typedefs fixes available.

Comment: While there may be type fixes available, that doesn't answer the question. I'm trying to understand why TS is throwing errors in an apparently ignored directory outside my current workspace

Comment: Facing just the same issue. Any luck here?

Answer (score 0):

You should try providing `"exclude"` option in `tsconfig.json`, but with `"**/node_modules"` glob. I think your problem is caused by multiple `node_modules` folders created by yarn workspaces, and this glob should exclude them all.

You could also enable `"skipLibCheck": true` flag, but this is is not considered good practice, because it will skip typechecking ALL `*.d.ts` files.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, not working unfortunately